# Tick labels in between colors (discrete colorer)

Tags: matplotlib, axis-labels, colorbar

Hi I want to put the ticklabels between colors (center of the intervals), and the figure is plotted by discrete colors. But the min value is not 0. How can I write the code to do that?
I used following code to do that, but what I got is wrong...

```
n_clusters = len(cbar_tick_label)
tick_locs = (np.arange(n_clusters)+0.5)*(n_clusters-1)/(n_clusters)
cbar.set_ticks(tick_locs)
cbar.set_ticklabels(cbar_tick_label)
```

This code is from question: [Discrete Color Bar with Tick labels in between colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496357/discrete-color-bar-with-tick-labels-in-between-colors). But it does not work when the min value of data is not zero.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there are `N` (e.g. 6) clusters. If you subdivide the range from the lowest number (e.g. `5`) to the highest number (e.g. `10`) into `N` equal parts, there will be a tick at every border between color cells. Subdividing into `2*N+1` equal parts, will also have a tick in the center of each color cell. Now, skipping every other of these `2*N+1` ticks will leave us with only the cell centers. So, `np.linspace(5, 10, 6*2+1)` are the ticks for borders and centers; taking `np.linspace(5, 10, 6*2+1)[1::2]` will be only the centers.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100)
c = np.random.randint(5, 11, x.shape)
n_clusters = c.max() - c.min() + 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = plt.get_cmap('inferno_r', n_clusters)
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap=cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar(scat)

tick_locs = np.linspace(c.min(), c.max(), 2 * n_clusters + 1)[1::2]
cbar_tick_label = np.arange(c.min(), c.max() + 1)
cbar.set_ticks(tick_locs)
cbar.set_ticklabels(cbar_tick_label)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]